# Getting error while populating a table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am learning to work with laravel and i'm having some troubles and i can't figure it out why. I have already changed names and I get the same result. I am trying to populate one table with some data from the database unsuccessfully. I would appreciate some help.
I keep getting the error : Class "App\Models\Contacto" not found

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\Contacto;

    public function show()
    {
       $data = Contacto::all();
       return view('contactos', ['contacto' => $data]);
    }
```

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contacto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamp = false;
    protected $table = 'contacto';
    protected $fillable = ['nt', 'consumo','id_comercial','tipo_contacto','nipc','nome'];  
}
```

**web**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactoController;

Route::get('/contactos', [ContactoController::class, 'show']);
```

**Blade**

```
            @foreach($contacto as $con)
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle">{{$con ['nt']}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{$con ['consumo']}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{$con ['id_comercial']}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{$con ['tipo_contacto']}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{$con ['nipc']}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{$con ['nome']}}</td>
                <td class="align-middle"><a href="cliente"><button type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-outline-primary mb-1 p-3">Abrir ficha contacto</button></a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Does your `Contacto` model have a **namespace**? If not, add: `namespace App\Models;`

Comment: Make sure it's in `app/Models/Contacto.php`, too. Not `app/Models/contacto.php`; case matters.

Comment: @cengsemihsahin it was the namespace, it needed the "models". Didn't noticed that. Thank you

Comment: @Tiago just run this command once `composer dump-autoload` and than try